# how can I get a running total by Date in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I wanna get a running total.

I could count records by date(it looks little complicated...anyway) and wanna get a running total with this result.
but it has an error in syntax as below.

> [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax;  check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use  near ''tb' inner join tb as 'otb' on date(otb.date) <=
>   date(tb.date) group by tb.date' at line 7

and my code is:

```
select 
tb.date, tb.counts, sum(otb.counts)
from
(select date(table.regdate) as date, count(*) as counts 
from table
where date(table.regdate) between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-05'
group by date(table.regdate)
order by regdate) as 'tb' 
inner join tb as 'otb' on date(otb.date) <= date(tb.date)
group by tb.date, tb.counts 
order by tb.date;
```

a select query is working in this code:

```
(select date(table.regdate) as date, count(*) as counts 
 from table
 where date(table.regdate) between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-05'
 group by date(table.regdate)
 order by regdate)
```

is work without any problem. And result table is as below

```
+------------+-------+
| 2020-01-01 | 20    |
| 2020-01-02 | 19    |
| 2020-01-03 | 8     |
| 2020-01-04 | 5     |
| 2020-01-05 | 9     |
+------------+-------+
```

but I wanna get running total by date like this

```
+------------+-------+
| 2020-01-01 | 20    |
| 2020-01-02 | 39    |
| 2020-01-03 | 47    |
| 2020-01-04 | 52    |
| 2020-01-05 | 61    |
+------------+-------+
```

Comment: table is a reserved word - do you actually have a table called table? Identifiers such as the aliases tb and otb should be backiticked rather than quoted (if quoted at all)

Comment: And if you search for mysql running total you will find many example how to do this

Comment: thank you everyone! I solve it and happy new year

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions.  Assuming the second query is what you are talking about:

```
select date(t.regdate) as date, count(*) as counts,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by date(t.regdate)) as running_count
from table t
where date(t.regdate) between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-05'
group by date(table.regdate)
order by date;
```